# Problemas com arrays num gerador de senhas em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, lista, password

Estou fazendo um gerador de senhas e não estou conseguindo juntar letras que estão separadas em um *array*.

```
from random import choice
minusculas = ['a','b','c','d','f','g','h']
maiusculas = ['A','B','C','D','F','G','H']
senha = []
pos=0
while pos < 16:
    aleatorio = choice(maiusculas)
    senha.append(aleatorio)
    pos+=1
    aleatorio = choice(minusculas)
    senha.append(aleatorio)
    pos+=1
print(senha)
```

O resultado é algo como: `['G', 'd', 'B', 'h', 'D', 'f', 'D', 'd', 'C', 'c', 'A', 'f', 'B', 'g', 'B', 'g']`

Eu queria juntar todas essa letras em uma única palavra.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Antes, um comentário importante: a [documentação do módulo `random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) diz claramente que este não deve ser usado para fins de segurança e criptografia, e sugere o uso do [módulo `secrets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) (disponível a partir do Python 3.6).

Dito isso, vamos ver como resolver com ambos os módulos.

---

Um detalhe: você está sempre adicionando uma letra maiúscula e outra minúscula, e outra maiúscula, e outra minúscula, etc. Isso não me parece aleatório o suficiente. Não seria melhor misturar todas as letras?

Além disso, a partir do Python 3.6 você pode usar [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) (repare no "choice**s**", no plural), passando a quantidade de elementos aleatórios que você quer extrair.

Depois, para juntar todas as letras em uma única string, use [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), como já indicaram as outras respostas.

Como no seu caso a senha tem 16 caracteres, ficaria assim:

```
from random import choices

minusculas = ['a','b','c','d','f','g','h']
maiusculas = ['A','B','C','D','F','G','H']

senha = ''.join(choices(minusculas + maiusculas, k=16))
```

Assim, a senha fica um pouco mais aleatória do que se você sempre alternar uma maiúscula com outra minúscula.

Um detalhe é que as letras não precisam estar em uma lista. Em Python, strings também são iteráveis, então poderia ser assim que também funciona:

```
minusculas = 'abcdefgh'
maiusculas = 'ABCDEFGH'
senha = ''.join(choices(minusculas + maiusculas, k=16))
```

Se estiver usando Python < 3.6 você pode simplesmente juntar as duas listas e chamar [`choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) várias vezes:

```
from random import choice

minusculas = ['a','b','c','d','f','g','h']
maiusculas = ['A','B','C','D','F','G','H']
letras = maiusculas + minusculas

senha = []
for _ in range(16):
    senha.append(choice(letras))

senha = ''.join(senha)
```

Ou, usando uma [*list comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions), bem mais sucinta e [*pythônica*](/q/192343/112052):

```
senha = ''.join(choice(letras) for _ in range(16))
```

Claro que ainda existe a chance da senha gerada só ter minúsculas (ou só maiúsculas), mas ainda sim me parece melhor do que tê-las sempre alternadas. De qualquer forma, ao final veremos como garantir isso com o módulo `secrets`.

---

Mas se a ideia é de fato alternar (sempre uma maiúscula e depois outra minúscula), aí não tem jeito, tem que chamar `choice` várias vezes:

```
from random import choice

minusculas = ['a','b','c','d','f','g','h']
maiusculas = ['A','B','C','D','F','G','H']

senha = []
for _ in range(8): # iterando 8 vezes para que a senha tenha 16 caracteres
    senha.append(choice(maiusculas))
    senha.append(choice(minusculas))

senha = ''.join(senha)
```

Ou, usando uma *list comprehension*, juntamente com o módulo [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
from random import choice
from itertools import chain

minusculas = ['a','b','c','d','f','g','h']
maiusculas = ['A','B','C','D','F','G','H']

senha = ''.join(chain.from_iterable((choice(maiusculas), choice(minusculas)) for _ in range(8)))
```

Mas se você fez assim apenas para "garantir" que sempre terá 8 letras maiúsculas e 8 minúsculas, uma opção seria embaralhar a lista ao final, pois pelo menos elas não ficam alternadas (se bem que o fato de você gerar sempre com 8 de cada torna a senha mais previsível do que se misturasse tudo, mas enfim):

```
import random
senha = []
for _ in range(8): # iterando 8 vezes para que a senha tenha 16 caracteres
    senha.append(random.choice(maiusculas))
    senha.append(random.choice(minusculas))

random.shuffle(senha) # embaralhar a string, para as maiúsculas não ficarem alternadas com minúsculas
senha = ''.join(senha)
```

---

## Módulo `secrets`

Como já dito no início, o módulo `random` não é o adequado para geração de senhas e quaisquer outros usos envolvendo criptografia e segurança, e a documentação sugere o uso do módulo `secrets`.

A forma de uso é bem parecida, tanto que existe um [método `choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#secrets.choice) similar ao existente em `random`:

```
from secrets import choice

minusculas = ['a','b','c','d','f','g','h']
maiusculas = ['A','B','C','D','F','G','H']
letras = maiusculas + minusculas

senha = ''.join(choice(letras) for _ in range(16))
```

O problema é que ainda sim existe a possibilidade da senha só ter letras minúsculas (ou só maiúsculas) - talvez seja por isso que você estava alternando? Enfim, [a própria documentação sugere um meio de contornar isso](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#recipes-and-best-practices):

```
while True:
    senha = ''.join(choice(letras) for _ in range(16))
    if (any(c.islower() for c in senha)
        and any(c.isupper() for c in senha)): # se tiver pelo menos uma maiúscula e uma minúscula, interrompe o loop
        break
```

Answer (score 4):

Não precisa fazer algo tão complexo. Não é necessário um *array* com os caracteres base, pode usar uma *string*. A contagem mais intuitiva é indo pelo tamanho dos caracteres individuais.

Se quisesse fazer uma função genérica, que permite outros conjuntos de caracteres teria que mudar um pouco esse código, não vou fazer inclusive porque não sei o requisito real. Por exemplo algumas soluções postadas aqui mudaram a semântica que o código original fez, não sei se pode. Se pode dá para resolver em uma linha. Eu mantive o sorteio intercalado entre maiúscula e minúscula. É bom? Não é, mas é o que foi feito.

```
from random import choice

minusculas = "abcdefgh"
maiusculas = "ABCDEFGH"
senha = []
pos = 0
while pos < 8:
    senha.append(choice(maiusculas))
    senha.append(choice(minusculas))
    pos += 1
print(''.join(senha))
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Fsjrut). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/pvkzjyqx-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/String/PasswordGenerator.py).

Poderia ter feito concatenação direta com a *string*? Poderia, mas não é eficiente.

Se não precisa manter a mesma semântica e ficar até melhor poderia fazer:

```
print(''.join([choice("abcdefghABCDEFGH") for i in range(16)]))
```

Para gerar senhas melhores o algoritmo precisaria ser bem diferente de todos esses, e claro, seria um pouco mais complexo, mas por necessidade e não por acidente.

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer unir esses caracteres em uma string única, você pode usar o [str.join(iterable)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
# os valores que você deu como exemplo
senha = ['G', 'd', 'B', 'h', 'D', 'f', 'D', 'd', 'C', 'c', 'A', 'f', 'B', 'g', 'B', 'g']

# une usando "nenhum" caractere como separador ('')
senha_concat = ''.join(senha)

print(senha_concat) # => GdBhDfDdCcAfBgBg
```

Answer (score 1):

Para juntar todas as letras em uma só string, basta utilizar o método de string [`join`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp) passando a lista como argumento. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
senha_lista = ["O","z","X","Q","r","n","d","K"]
senha_string = "".join(senha_lista)
```

É possível encurtar ainda mais o seu código criando uma função e utilizando [*list comprehension*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34835951/11679204) para obter a lista de letras em uma única linha. Veja o código abaixo:

```
def get_random_password(chars, length = 10):

    letters = [choice(chars) for i in range(length)]
    return "".join(letters)

chars = ['a','b','c','d','f','g','h','A','B','C','D','F','G','H']
password = get_random_password(chars, 16)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use uma variável tipo texto para a senha e incremente a cada passo do seu loop.

```
from random import choice
minusculas = ['a','b','c','d','f','g','h']
maiusculas = ['A','B','C','D','F','G','H']
pos=0
senha = ''
while pos < 16:
    aleatorio = choice(maiusculas)
    senha = senha + aleatorio
    pos+=1
    aleatorio = choice(minusculas)
    senha = senha + aleatorio
    pos+=1
print(senha)
```