# Como gerar chave aleatória em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou aprendendo a programar com Python e queria saber como posso gerar uma "chave" de autenticação com letras e números, por exemplo: `A9281BEKS219`

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/461052/112052

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Problemas com arrays num gerador de senhas em Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/461052/problemas-com-arrays-num-gerador-de-senhas-em-python)

Answer (score 5):

Uma maneira de fazer o que deseja é utilizando as funções do pacote [`random`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html), utilizar a função [`choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice).

Dito isto um exemplo de implementação seria:

```
import random
escolhas_possiveis = 'ABC123'
print(random.choice(escolhas_possiveis))
```

Se executar este código vai ver que será sorteado letras aleatórias que fazem parte do conjunto `'ABC123'`, desta forma basta agora saber o tamanho da string e o conjunto de caracteres que faz parte da sequência que deseja sortear. De acordo com a sequência que passou ela possui 13 caracteres. Uma implementação possível seria:

```
import random
escolhas_possiveis = 'ABC123'
resultado = ''
for i in range(12):
    resultado += random.choice(escolhas_possiveis)
print(resultado)
# 2CA2AB2AA333
```

O Python possui algumas funções `"helpers"` que facilitam esta tarefa, pode importar os caracteres ASCII utilizando funções do módulo `string` da seguinte forma:

```
import string
import random
escolhas_possiveis = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
# equivalente à: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789
resultado = ''
for i in range(12):
    resultado += random.choice(escolhas_possiveis)

print(resultado)
```

Existem também outras possibilidades de funções para tratar `Operações comuns com caracteres` por ex:

1. `ascii_letters`
2. `ascii_lowercase`
3. `ascii_uppercase`

Você pode utilizar essas funções para compor o seu alfabeto com as escolhas possíveis para poder gerar as chaves aleatórias, por exemplo, se quiser gerar apenas valores aleatórios com valores de minúsculos, deve utilizar a função `ascii_lowercase` por exemplo.

Consulte a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) para consultar todas as opções.

### Gerando tokens de autenticação seguros (Python 3.6+)

Existe também a possibilidade de utilizar o módulo [`secrets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#generating-tokens)
para geração de tokens seguros.

O módulo `secrets` é usado para gerar números aleatórios criptograficamente fortes adequados para gerenciar dados como senhas, autenticação de conta, tokens de segurança.

Ele deve ser usados de preferência ao gerador de números pseudo-aleatórios padrão no módulo `random`, que é projetado para modelagem e simulação, não para segurança ou criptografia.

Segue um exemplo de utilização do módulo `secrets`:

```
import secrets

secrets.token_hex(64)
# '19e07dba673b058f997d580ca4d79a443a484a02a35537de908276c40fd3446b89d701649ab4ddc4e582ba4680966e73445812b6a926036c9f6e22b3d49b8837'
```

A função `token_hex` retorna uma string de texto aleatória, em hexadecimal. A string possui `nbytes` aleatórios, que para este caso é 64, cada byte convertido em dois dígitos hexadecimais. Se `nbytes` for `None` ou não fornecido é utilizado um valor padrão razoável.

Sugiro ler a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/secrets.html#generating-tokens) detalhadamente e escolher o método que melhor se encaixa para o seu caso de uso.

Comment: Reverti a edição porque o *backtick* (`\``) deve ser usado apenas para código. Ver também o [Guia de Estilo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1297/112052): "*Não use `\`\`` (código-inline) para dar ênfase ou para formatar siglas ou nomes próprios. A formatação de código deve ser reservada somente para código e assemelhados*"

Answer (score 0):

Em python existe uma biblioteca que nos permite fazer isso, random.

Para criar esta string aleatória vamos utilizar dois módulos:

```
string;
random;
```

```
import string
import random

def gerar_chave(size=12, chars=string.ascii_letters + string.digits):
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

print(gerar_chave()) #Uzzre9tOXTZE
print(gerar_chave()) #dmeWLOJ4UqJD
print(gerar_chave()) #q0e0DuJa2WK7
```

E por fim temos o método join, que é utilizado para unir a essa string

A última instrução dessa função é retornar o que foi gerado aleatóriamente pelo código de Python

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).